# Google Spreadsheets Regex Case Insensitive (Regexreplace)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm trying to create a case insensitive regex query in Google Spreadsheets with the regexreplace function. Is that possible? I've tried the \i flag and got a #REF error saying the expression was invalid: =regexreplace("Test","t\i","") gives an error when I would hope to get "es" as the final result.

Is it possible? Is there a flag for case sensitivity in Google Spreadsheets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wasn't even aware they'd added regex to Google Spreadsheets

Comment: You may want to move the checkmark to the [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29094096)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

<strike>AFAIK, the only way to enable case-insensitive matching is JavaScript API in google docs.</strike>

Apparently, **RE2** syntax does support the inline `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier:

```
=REGEXREPLACE("Test", "(?i)t", "")
```

An alternative that will work is using a Character class, adding both cases of the letter `T`..

```
=REGEXREPLACE("Test", "[Tt]", "")
```

Comment: Google Sheets does allow specific regex flags, including `i` for case-insensitivity.  See [Alexander Ivanov's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29094096/445295).

Comment: [re2 supports (?i) flag](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt), consider updating the answer since it sits here as the accepted one.

Answer (score 20):

I found this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE("Test","(?i)t","")
```

It returns what you want

```
es
```

[google/re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Comment: It works because you are adding a flag to your regular expression. The "i" flag stands for case-insensitive matching, therefore it will match any lower or uppercase T. See https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt

Answer (score 3):

As Alexander Ivanov wrote,

> Yes, I'm understand that this topic has resolved. But I found something fancy!
>
> =REGEXREPLACE("Test","(?i)t","") It returns what you want
>
> es
>
> P.S.: Please, if somebody knows why it works then comment.

Google uses their own re2 regular expressions engine.
Using  (?i) is allowing you to set the flags for case insensitive search
https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html

Answer (score -1):

There is NO flag for case sensitivity
If you have a longer string and you want to make it case insensitive you cold try use a lowercase regular expression and make your test lowercase usign the function lower:
    =REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(string), regex_in_lowercase, replacement)
in your specific case:
    =REGEXREPLACE(LOWER("test"), "t", "")
The problem is that a capture expression with be in lowercase! 
source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/7kNb9LGeIfM

Comment: The above may have been true in the past, but it isn't now. To be clear, the above is incorrect - there IS a flag for case insensitivity and it works as you would hope - based on actually testing the following: "(?i)SOMESTRING" matches all of "SOMESTRING", "SomeString", "Somestring", "somestring".

Comment: Though this is a very old answer, let me add my little two cents. In a scenario where you want the regexp to be dynamic and contained in another cell, this is the best approach as there is no chance to interpolate cell content with a regexpr in line. So the answer - imho - shouldn't have been demoted in such a way.