# Inverse of vlookup

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

How do I find which value in an array is substring of a single value. For example lookup array `{wrestling,judo,kungfu}` value `www.wresting.com` the result should be `wrestling`

Comment: In VBA, For Each Item in Array ... `If Instr(1, Value, Item) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for google sheets:

```
=FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH("www.wrestling.com",A:A),A:A<>"")
```

if col A contains `{wrestling,judo,kungfu}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response is there a way to ignore case in regexmatch

Comment: This did the trick `=FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH("www.wrestling.com","(?i)"&A:A),A:A<>"")`

Comment: here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644243/google-spreadsheets-regex-case-insensitive-regexreplace