# Google Sheets Highlighting using Conditional Formatting for Text that DOESN'T Contain "x" - TWO Criteria

Tags: regex, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I plan to use Google Sheet's conditional formatting to highlight cells where the text DOES NOT contain:

- Retail
- FinServ
- Manufacturing
- Field Service
- Managed Services
- Digital Transformation
- Ecommerce
- Data and Analytics

For the above phrases, I want to be able to add additional details, separated by an underscore (_), and have the row still NOT be highlighted. For ex: Retail_Blog should still NOT be highlighted because it begins with one of the phrases above.

To do this, I'm currently using the formula:

`=regexmatch(F:F,"Retail|FinServ|Manufacturing|Field Service|Managed Services|Digital Transformation|Ecommerce|Data and Analytics")=FALSE`

This formula works great for the specifications above, but I also would like the formula to do adhere to another rule.

For the phrases below, I would like the formula to highlight cells if they DON'T EXACTLY match the phrases. For ex: "Meetings" should NOT be highlighted, but "meetings," "Meeting," and "Meetings_whatever" SHOULD be highlighted.

- Meetings
- Website Updates
- Press Release and Distribution
- Calendar Planning

Also, this formula would be for the range F:F.

Comment: The formula uses case sensitive regular expressions. Have you already tried to do something similar like adding the second set of phrases separating them by `|`? Have you considered to use Google Sheets functions like AND(), OR(), SEARCH(), FIND() among other?

Comment: By the way "Let me know..." invites primarily opinion based answers which could make the question to be closed.

Comment: Combine the second set with NOT(regexmatch(,"|"))

Comment: @Rubén the function is currently working by separating the terms with | and it didn't with commas, so that wouldn't work in this case. SEARCH and FIND are only looking for the first occurence, and there may be many occurrences I need to track. The OR function wasn't working for me which is why I went with regexmatch.

Comment: @I'-'I I tried that and it's just highlighting whatever isn't being highlighted from the first function and not following my specific rules

Comment: Have you tried to set two rules?

Comment: @Rubén yes I have, but I can't get the second one to work. I tried this formula to make sure Meeting is logged correctly, but it's not working: =IF(F:F="Meeting", true, IF(F:F="meeting", false, IF(F:F="Meetings", false, false)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Formula

`=regexmatch(F:F,"Retail|FinServ|Manufacturing|Field Service|Managed Services|Digital Transformation|Ecommerce|Data and Analytics|^Meetings$|^Website Updates$|^Press Release and Distribution$|^Calendar Planning$")=FALSE`

## Explanation

- `^` means match start
- `$` means match end

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to make the custom formula for the conditional formatting not case sensitive?

Comment: @KatieRosenholm, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24644243/1595451

Comment: I don't think that would work because of the multiple conditions (separated by | not ,) that my formula has: =regexmatch(F:F,"^Press Release and Distribution|^Website Updates|^Meetings|^Calendar Planning|^FinServ|^Manufacturing|^Retail|^Field Service|^Managed Services|^Digital Transformation|Ecommerce|^Data and Analytics|^Hitachi Solutions / MSFT Partner")=FALSE