# Find ALL matching words in a cell with Nested Regex or other?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to identify if particular text can be found in a cell in Google Spreadsheets like this example:

| Text | Desired Output |
| --- | --- |
| Cynthia and Dale went to the store | Cynthia, Dale |
| Cynthia went to the store | Cynthia |

Unfortunately using this code
`IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"Bob"),"Bob",IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"Cynthia"),"Cynthia",IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"Dale"),"Dale","Nobody")))`

Only returns the first REGEX match found, not multiple ones as I would like.

Any suggestions for modifying the formula would be helpful.

A spreadsheet can be found with the examples and code here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YuyFdEbqgZaSL2IbyyalVLLXsXrIAuqtaxCTXLhSuEU/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: You could make a column for each name (e.g. the Bob column contains Bob or nothing) and then another column where you concatenate those columns and if the result is empty put in Nobody.

Comment: You may also use a function in GAS, see [Multiple regex matches in Google Sheets formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62704859/3832970). It would look like `=ExtractAllRegex(A2, "\b(Bob|Cynthia|Dale)\b", 0, ", ")`. It is easy to adapt it to output `Nobody` upon no match, too, using `return matches.length > 0 ? [matches.join(separator)] : "Nobody";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,".*?\b(Bob|Dale|Cynthia)\b|.*","$1 "))," ",", "))
```

This will spill down the column.

---

If you need to fill the empty cells with 'Nobody', maybe an nested `REGEXREPLACE()` would work:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="","",REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,".*?\b(Bob|Dale|Cynthia)\b|.*","$1 "))," ",", "),"^$","Nobody")))
```

Or without a 2nd replace:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="","",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A&" Nobody","(?:.*?\b(Bob|Dale|Cynthia)\b|^.*(Nobody)$|.+)","$1 $2"))," ",", ")))
```

Comment: Thanks anyone know if I can add an I experession to make formula recognize any case? Similar to this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644243/google-spreadsheets-regex-case-insensitive-regexreplace/24645121

Comment: Seems this may work but would also be useful to extract out everything in lower case or upper case?

`=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,".*?\b((?i)Bob|Dale|Cynthia)\b|.*","$1 "))," ",", "))`

Comment: @MMsmithH, if the answer helped and answered your question you are welcome to tick the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: How might I add to this formula, so that the Bob|Dale|Cynthia be replaced by another specified substitute such as Bob Last Name|Cynthia_V_Smith|Dale_is_Cool

Comment: How might I add to this formula, so that the Bob|Dale|Cynthia be replaced by another specified substitute such as Bob Last Name|Cynthia_V_Smith|Dale_is_Cool?

Substitute formula is used in this Google Sheet in the second tab is used to replace with specified values in spreadsheet using this formula

SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B3,INDEX($E$3:$E$5,1),INDEX($F$3:$F$5,1)), INDEX($E$3:$E$5,2),INDEX($F$3:$F$5,2)),INDEX($E$3:$E$5,3),INDEX($F$3:$F$5,3))

Comment: @mmsmith, new questions get new posts on SO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71227476/17835120